# Mapping unique list to current dataset in Pentaho Javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I need to generate an unique list  of values and assign it dynamically in java script to each row of a data set.
I understand that the way the Modified Javascript value works is by applying the same script to each row, so how can I generate a unique list of values (in javascript) and apply one value of the list to each row of the dataset. The unique list has to be generated only once; do I need to do it outside of a Modified Java Script Value?

Comment: But u can pass row number to Java Script and use it to make decision on currently generating value.

Comment: Or u can generate unique values  and join streams together later on